Inductor Current Going Below Zero in DCM
I'm currently studying the Continuous Conduction Mode (CCM) and Discontinuous Conduction Mode (DCM) behaviors in buck converters and running simulations to visualize the differences. As I understand it:

CCM occurs when the current through the inductor is consistently above zero throughout the switching cycle.
DCM happens when the load is light, causing the inductor current to drop to zero during the switch-off phase. This in turn causes the outout voltage go up to match the slope of the dropping current.

However, in my simulations, I'm observing something unexpected. When the buck converter transitions to DCM, the inductor current (green waveform) doesn’t just drop to zero—it actually goes below zero.
When the switch turns off, the inductor current and diode current fall to zero, as expected for DCM.
The diode current stays at zero, but the inductor current dips into negative values, drawing current in the reverse direction from the voltage source.
This is confusing because with the switch off, I wouldn’t expect the inductor to draw current from the source. I'm wondering if I made a mistake in my circuit design or if there’s something fundamental about DCM behavior that I’m missing.
Any insights into why this might be happening or suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!


Not all the energy can be transferred from inductor to output capacitor/load because of the flyback diode non-idealities. What happens is that this residual energy is passed into the drain-source capacitance of the MOSFET and it rings with the inductor for a short while. That is also why you see it in i(V7) because it's part of the series tuned circuit that forms.

It's a common phenomena but, doesn't show itself in CCM because the flyback diode is always conducting a decent amount when called into action.

suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated

Nothing to troubleshoot = it's a benign side-effect.

Thank you very much for your explanation. I followed your suggestion and pushed the simulation further into DCM, and there it is much clearer that the current does drop to 0A with slight ringing.

What you are seeing is reverse recovery current (charge; often QRR in the data sheet) of the diode. Basically when the diode was forward biased with higher current, the internal pn junction develops a significant charge stored in it. When the diode becomes reverse biased (e.g. at he end of a DCM cycle), the charge acts somewhat like a capacitance and allows negative L current to flow.
Note that CCM doesn't strictly require only positive inductor current. In a DCDC with synchronous rectification (e.g. a MOSFET in place of the diode, switched complimentarily to the 1st FET), you do have negative current. This is common in high performance DCDC converters. It may be slightly less efficient than DCM, but has the same dynamics as full positive current and this improves some types of load response.
